# Stop mailto: from opening mail app iMac

Tags: html, email, anchor

I have a link that, when clicked on, opens up the mail app. Can I stop it from doing this, and open up a tab in the browser instead?

```
<a href="mailto:foo@foo.com">
    Send mail
</a>
```

Comment: The mail app is determined by the configuration of the browser; you can’t affect it from your page code.

Comment: Is JavaScript an option? You could add an event listener to the link that intercepts clicks, prevents the default action and instead runs your own function to open a new tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could hijack all clicks on e-mail links with this script:

```
$("a[href^='mailto:']").click(function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  window.open('https://mail.google.com');
});
```

Note: this script requires jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

**mailto** calls the users default email client. It does not open a window or tab in any instance.

If you want to remain on your page and open a new tab on click of send mail link , use window.open it will open a new tab and your outlook gets open
.ts

```
  newwindow(ev){
      window.open("mailto:foo@foo.com" , "_blank");
      ev.preventDefault();
    }
```

.html

```
   <a (click)="newwindow(event)" href="mailto:foo@foo.com">
        Send mail
    </a>
```

Right now, new browsers support some web mail interfaces like gmail,
So we can simply open a new window and add a fallback using preventDefault and default link redirection.